# cocoa:how to use a web view property created in a class derived from NSViewController in an app delegate class?

Tags: cocoa

The code in my app delegate class:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request newFrameName:(NSString *)frameName decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener{
NSLog(@"hello");
NSTabViewItem *newItem=[[NSTabViewItem alloc] init];



  NSInteger index = [_tabView numberOfTabViewItems];
[_tabView  insertTabViewItem:newItem atIndex:index];
[newItem setLabel:@"Empty Tab" ];
//[_tabView  selectPreviousTabViewItem:@"select"];
newVC =[[newViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"newViewController" bundle:nil];
[[_tabView .tabViewItems objectAtIndex:index] setView:[newVC view]];
newViewController *obj=[newViewController alloc]init];
[obj.newWebView mainframe]loadrequest:request];
```

}

This code is not loading the web view with the requested url.
Here newWebView is the web view property i have created in newViewController class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what are you trying to do?

```
newViewController *obj=[[newViewController alloc]init];
```

is allocating a brand new object that you're never sticking into the user interface. Hence, `obj.newWebView` will never show up either.

I'm not sure, but I think what you're looking for is

```
[[newVC.newWebView mainframe]loadrequest:request];
```

instead? There's also a couple missing brackets in your code, but I assume they're just typos!